# AWS Cognito Only Working in USEast1

Tags: ios, amazon-cognito

I have an iOS app written in Swift using the AWS Cognito APIs. Connecting to USEast1 works as expected and authenticates my user

```
var awsProperties = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("AWS", ofType: "plist")!)
var credentialsProvider : AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider
var loggedIn = false

override init() {
    credentialsProvider  = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider.credentialsWithRegionType(
        AWSRegionType.USEast1,
        accountId:awsProperties?.valueForKey(GlobalConstants.AccountId) as String,
        identityPoolId:awsProperties?.valueForKey(GlobalConstants.USIdentityPoolId) as String,
        unauthRoleArn:awsProperties?.valueForKey(GlobalConstants.UnauthDefaultRole) as String,
        authRoleArn:awsProperties?.valueForKey(GlobalConstants.AuthDefaultRole) as String)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
    let defaultServiceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(
        region: AWSRegionType.USEast1,
        credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().setDefaultServiceConfiguration(defaultServiceConfiguration)
    credentialsProvider.getIdentityId().continueWithBlock { (task: BFTask!) -> AnyObject! in
        if((task.error) != nil) {
            NSLog("%@", task.error)
        } else {
            NSLog("%@", self.credentialsProvider.identityId)
            self.loggedIn = true
        }
        return self.loggedIn
    }

    return true
}
```

I have the necessary code to allow login against G+ in a separate login controller, with nothing region specific.

If however I use the exact same code, but changing the region to EUWest1 and using my EU based Identify Pool I get the following exception:

```
AWSiOSSDKv2 [Error] AWSCredentialsProvider.m line:453 | __46-[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider getIdentityId]_block_invoke | In refresh, but identityId is nil.
AWSiOSSDKv2 [Error] AWSCredentialsProvider.m line:454 | __46-[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider getIdentityId]_block_invoke | Result from getIdentityId is (null)
```

The trust policy on my IAM Role allows access to both Identity Pools:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "accounts.google.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": [
            "eu-west-1:XXXXXX",
            "us-east-1:XXXXXX"
          ]
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Am I missing somewhere I should be overriding the region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, after struggling with this for several days I've figured out the problem having finally posted to SO.

The problem was that there was a previous version of the AWS iOS SDK linked on the Framework Search Paths, which did not have EUCentral1. The inclusion of that in the enum appears to have changed the indexes and given that Cognito is only supported in USEast1 and EUWest1 it was attempting to authenticate against an incorrect region.